# Second query only executed after CTE end

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query. However, I have the following problem: table 1 is such a huge table that has performance issues if not filtering the data appropriately pre joining with other tables. For that reason, I've used a CTE (aux) which I use to filter the data that I'm going to need in the main query. Is there a way (maybe a hint) to tell the main query that it should only plan according to aux and not to table 1?

```
WITH aux AS (
    SELECT
        col1, col4
    FROM
        -- This is my huge table
        table1
    WHERE
        col2 IS NULL
        AND col3 > 0
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aux t1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            table2 t2
        WHERE
            t2.col4 = t1.col4
            AND t2.col5 > 100
    );
```

Comment: Do you mean   `..FROM   aux t2..` ? Yes it's quite correct syntax.

Comment: What is your Postgres version? Also Show us the query plan, and what you want.

Comment: BTW `t2.col4 = t1.col4` t1 (=aux) doesn't have a column col4. It only has col1.

Comment: @wildplasser I'm using Oracle 12.1 and I've just amended my query to fetch t4 from aux.

Comment: Oops, sorry! [dont know about Oracle]

Comment: @Serg no, I mean table2 t2.

Comment: You can try `WITH aux AS (
    SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */
        col1, col4`

Comment: @Serg just trying but not working :(

Comment: Try adding `and rownum >= 1` to any CTEs, subqueries, or inline views that you want to run as-is without any optimizer transformations.